# How can I convert EnumerableRowCollection<string[]> to a regular string array?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, linq

How can I convert EnumerableRowCollection to a regular string array?

Here is my code.

```
var trackerCodes = from a in excelData.AsEnumerable() select new[] { a[TrackerCodeColumnIndex].ToString() };

var resizeInfo = from a in excelData.AsEnumerable() select new[] { a[ResizeInfoColumnIndex].ToString() };
```

I want to convert those two EnumerableRowCollections to a regular string arrays.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why does your `select` have `new[]` instead of just returning the `string`s, giving you two `IEnumerable<string>` that you can then use with `ToArray`?

Comment: I've copied this code from another thread. And by changing it to string the code won't compile. However, I've already found a solution but it would be great if you can show me the code of what you're explaining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have some need for returning `IEnumerable<string[]>`, just return `IEnumerable<string>`:

```
var trackerCodes = from a in excelData.AsEnumerable() select a[TrackerCodeColumnIndex].ToString();
var resizeInfo = from a in excelData.AsEnumerable() select a[ResizeInfoColumnIndex].ToString();
```

Then you can transform each to an array by:

```
var trackerCodesArray = trackerCodes.ToArray();
var resizeInfoArray = resizeInfo.ToArray();
```

Of course, if you just want the array you could combine them into a single expression:

```
var trackerCodes = (from a in excelData.AsEnumerable() select a[TrackerCodeColumnIndex].ToString()).ToArray();
var resizeInfo = (from a in excelData.AsEnumerable() select a[ResizeInfoColumnIndex].ToString()).ToArray();
```

Though at that point I would be tempted to use lambda / fluent query syntax:

```
var trackerCodes = excelData.AsEnumerable().Select(a => a[TrackerCodeColumnIndex].ToString()).ToArray();
var resizeInfo = excelData.AsEnumerable().Select(a => a[ResizeInfoColumnIndex].ToString()).ToArray();
```

Of course, `.Field<string>(index)` is generaly preferred instead of `[index].ToString()`.

And, if you do not specifically need an array, using `ToList` is better than using `ToArray`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Nailed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SelectMany method of Linq after put both in an enumerable. For ex:

```
var superArray = (new[] {trackerCodes, resizeInfo}).SelectMany(x => x);
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to combine them. My end goal is to make a dictionary where the Key is the respective value from trackerCodes and the value is the respective value from resizeInfo. They're both with equal size.

Comment: Why you need to "select new[] ..." just "select a[TrackerCodeColumnIndex].ToString()" and you will get IEnumerable<string> then you can use .ToArray() method. I think the problem is "new[] {...}" as you are creating an array of one string value for each string value

Comment: var trackerCodes = from a in excelData.AsEnumerable() select string a[TrackerCodeColumnIndex].ToString(); this isn't compiling either. I am sorry I have never used that kind of structure before.

Comment: As I mention in my comment it is "select a[TrackerCodeColumnIndex].ToString()" without the word "string", you are adding string

Answer (score 0):

```cs
    List<string> trackerCodes = excelData.AsEnumerable()
                                         .Select(r => r.Field<string("START"))
                                         .ToList();
```